# How does paying off pending credit card charges effect credit score?

Tags: credit-score, payment

I pay off my credit cards online almost daily. Usually while charges are still pending so my account almost always shows a zero balance. I have a great credit score but I'd love to reach the 850 mark. When I check my score on experian it says "There is insufficient or no recent activity on credit cards and/or bank-issued open-ended accounts" even though I've used credit cards for nearly every purchase for the past 8 years or so. Would I be better off waiting until the due date to make payments?

Thanks!

Comment: You answered your own question. Every time your card reports, it shows a 0 balance, so you got dinged by whatever credit model they're showing.

Comment: As someone with a FICO score of 829 as of a couple of weeks ago, I can say with near certainly you are doing it wrong. First and most obvious is what has been said already, reporting a zero balance shows no responsible usage. I use my cards, pay the statement balance in full by the due date, that ACTUALLY helps your score. I also regularly increase my credit limits so my usage % gets lower by simple math. You need to look into understanding how credit scoring works, what you are doing is literally shooting yourself in the foot and wondering why it hurts.

Answer (score 2):

Paying off your card daily has very little benefit or effect on credit score. Rating agencies don't get reports of your balance daily (only every 30-45 days), so paying it daily is just extra work. Paying weekly *might* help, but paying at least the minimum balance monthly will be much more impactful to your score. Paying the *full* balance monthly will have the same financial effect.

I should also note that there is very little practical benefit from an 850 score versus an 800, and much of your score is based on the average age of credit, and often time actions will help one aspect of your score while hurting another. For example, adding a loan to improve "mix of credit" will add an inquiry and reduce the average age of credit, which lower your score.